# Fast method of Geospatial indexing of half million polygons in Lucene

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, lucene, geospatial, geohashing

I am trying to find intersecting geo-hashes(upto precision length 6) of around half million polygons. For every polygon I have to find all the geohashes(upto precision length 6) inside that polygon and index it. I have tried using postgis st_geohash and st_intersect and then storing it in redis but it is very slow for my use-case. I need to index half million polygon's geohashes in 10 mins.

I read it that its possible to do so using [lucene](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2014/04/11/indexing-polygons-in-lucene-with-accuracy/). I tried searching 'geo-spatial indexing a polygon' but couldn't find a good link.
I am a beginner in elastic search and lucene.

Kindly, tell me how to do it or point me in the right direction.

Regards,